# Search in select list?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

i would like make somethings:

```
<select>
    <option value=""> Please select </option>
    <option value="search"> < /input search > </option>
    <option value="name1"> name1 </option>
    <option value="aname2"> aname2 </option>
    <option value="bname3"> bname3 </option>
    <option value="bname4"> bname4 </option>
    <option value="cname5"> cname5 </option>
    <option value="cname6"> cname6 </option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvJ5d/1/

If i set/mouseover/click option SEARCH then i would like search in others option value. 
I have select with 300 option. For example if i write **b** then this show me in list only **bname3** and **bname4** .

How can make somethings? may be something like. I must use jQuery, not Mototools etc

Comment: What is this:  `< /input search >` - also have a look at [Filter Select jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=filter+select+jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Chosen, i think this is the best plugin:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to do this with a basic select as it is not possible. But jQuery UI has autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ which would be perfect for you.

Here's a more specific example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jGme9/

Answer (score 1):

you can use autocomplete from [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

```
var data = [ {text:'Link A', url:'/page1'}, {text:'Link B', url: '/page2'} ];
$("#selectid").autocomplete(data, {
    formatItem: function(item) {
        return item.text;
    }
}).result(function(event, item) {
      location.href = item.url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you allow there to be a separate input field for the query and do not need to offload the search to the server, this could be written like this:

```
<script>
function bind_select_search(srch, select, arr_name) {    
  window[arr_name] = []
  $(select + " option").each(function(){                    
        window[arr_name][this.value] = this.text
  })
  $(srch).keyup(function(e) {
      text = $(srch).val()
      if (text != '' || e.keyCode == 8) {
            arr = window[arr_name]
            $(select + " option").remove()                          
          tmp  = ''
          for (key in arr) {
              option_text = arr[key].toLowerCase()
              if (option_text.search(text.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) {                     
                  tmp += '<option value="'+key+'">'+ arr[key] +'</option>'
              }
          }
          $(select).append(tmp)
       }
   })
  $(srch).keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 8) // Backspace
              $(srch).trigger('keyup')
  })

}





</script>
```

Form:

```
<input id="srch" type="text" name="search">    
<select id="slct">
    <option value="1">London</option>
    <option value="2">New York</option>
    <option value="3">Paris</option>
    <option value="4">Oslo</option>
    <option value="5">Berlin</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X72G7/3/